# Matlab kalman filter in python

Tags: python, matlab, kalman-filter

is there a filter function of kalman in Python that works in the same way as the Kalman function of matlab?

```
[kest] = kalman(sys,Qn,Rn)
```

The idea is that the function receives as parameters a space of states and the respective weight matrices (it is to implement an LQR controller)

Comment: Yesterday there was an answer regarding pykalman library here. Does not it solve the problem correctly?

Comment: No, it has not helped me since it does not work with a state space

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the ovtave source code for the kalman filter and implemented it in python. Anyway, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pyKalman](https://pykalman.github.io/) library. See the [sin example](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman/blob/master/examples/standard/plot_sin.py) followed by the [filter example](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman/blob/master/examples/standard/plot_filter.py).

It is not exactly like Matlab but it is easy enough to use.